# Is there any command code to clear I/O area while running program in MarsPlus?

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I made a code by mips language using MarsPlus and  I want to clear every current outputs in console.
So if my program ask user input and if user input is 1, I want to make it to clear every output made by this time. I don't want to exit the program, I just want to clear.
Is there any way?

Comment: Does printing a string of 20 or 30 newlines work?  Or do you need to clear the scrollback, too?

Comment: I haven't used http://www.calebhoff.com/2018/10/mars-plus.html though, only regular MARS.  Does MarsPlus come with source that ways MARS does?  (`.java` files are inside the `.jar`)

Comment: yes clear the scrollback too..